# Android how to load a new Fragment onClick of ListView Header

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface, android-fragments

How can I target the onClick listener for the listView Header. Because If I click on the header at moment the app crash, I want to load a new fragment when click on the header.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile_fragment, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");

// Setup Views
productsListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.productsGridView);
header = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_product_header, null);
productsListView.addHeaderView(header);

coverImage          = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.imageCover);
profileImage        = (BootstrapCircleThumbnail)header.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
textViewUserName    = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
textViewUserEmail   = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);



// Adapter
productsListView.setAdapter(adapter = new ProductsAdapter());
// On Item clicked
productsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onClick of gridview" + position);


        ProductsDataModel data = adapter.getItem(position);

        Fragment mFragment = null;      
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        mFragment = new ProductFragment().newInstance("Product Page");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("product_id", data.product_id);

        mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        if (mFragment != null){     
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content_frame, mFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }//end onItemClick
});//end gridview.setOnItemClickListener
```

If I use: `ProductsDataModel data = adapter.getItem(position);`
When Click on header, it will open the first item on the ListView

If I use :  `ProductsDataModel data = adapter.getItem(position -1);`
this is the error:

```
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at com.dec.sellbess06.fragments.UserProfileFragment$ProductsAdapter.getItem(UserProfileFragment.java:197)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at com.dec.sellbess06.fragments.UserProfileFragment$1.onItemClick(UserProfileFragment.java:130)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2815)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3574)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-09 14:00:13.481: E/AndroidRuntime(29718):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please share the error logcat. and where is the click of header ??

Comment: Hello  SweetWisher , I have updated my question, thanks

Comment: obviously poisition-1 will give you -1 of you click 0th element, are you getting header click from `ItemClick` only ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get *HeaderView*'s Click on `OnItemClickListener`. Simlpy handle `OnClick` of HeaderView as :

```
header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
         // Do your stuff
    }
});
```

Don't forget to set Clickable of headerView

```
header.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Thank you SweetWisher ツ.